# Understanding min-key with apply

Tags: clojure

I am reading a piece of code like this:

`(apply min-key {:1 1, :2 0, :3 1, :4 10000, :5 1} #{:1 :3 :4 :5}) => :3`

I'm not sure why this returns :3 and not :1

Can someone clarify it for me ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you take a look at min-key source, you'll see that it compares value with

`(if (< v1 v2) v1 v2)` , that means if they are equal, it takes the second one. So for multiple keys provided that have equal values it will always choose the last one, in your case :3

That is happening, because you use a set of values, whose internal order differs from the input:

in repl:

```
user> #{:1 :3 :4 :5}
#{:4 :1 :5 :3}
```

so, in this order, :3 is the last key checked.

Comment: Yes @leetwinski, thanks for your answer. I just see that now. (about the last one). thanks

Answer (score 2):

`min-key` returns an element `x` from `#{:1 :3 :4 :5}` such as `(k x)` is minimal, where `k` is your map. The value associated with  `:3` in that map is 1, which is the minimal value. Granted, other keys, like `:1` and `:5` have the same value, but keys are not compared, only values. Which of the keys returning the minimal value is returned probably depends on arbitrary factors such as the internal order of traversal of your set.

Comment: Great. Thanks for you answer @coredump.